# Функция возвращается в исходное положение после окончания

Tags: javascript, html

Недавно начал учить JS. Есть некий блок  и некая кнопка, так вот, по нажатию на кнопку у блока меняются его координаты и расположение его фона. А алерт выводит координаты блока. Всё срабатывает, всё хорошо, вот только работает оно ровно до момента нажатия "ок" в алерте, после чего возвращается на исходную позицию. Знающие люди, пожалуйста, подскажите, как это поправить?

```html
<div id="card"></div>
<button id="knopka" left="100px">Рандом</button>
<script>
  var  value4;
  var  value5;
  var  value6;
  var  value7;
knopka.onclick = function getRandomInt() { 

value4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (800 - 1)) + 1 ;
card.style.top=""+value4+"px";
value5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1280 - 1)) + 1 ;
card.style.left=""+value5+"px";
value6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1) - 1) * 143 ;
value7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1) - 1) * 98.46 ;
card.style.backgroundPosition="left "+value7+"px top "+value6+"px";
alert("X: "+value5+" Y: "+value4+"");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Это весь код, который используется на странице? Скорее всего там есть еще какой-то код, который выполняется и сбрасывает значения.

Answer (score 1):

В общем плане, как я понимаю, код рабочий, но блок никуда не перемещается. Просто меняются его координаты, но не положение. А причина в этом, что по-умолчанию используется `display: block;`

Попробуйте просто изменить стиль соответствующего элемента, например:

```
<div style="position: absolute;" id="card">CARD</div>
```

Вот пример рабочий: http://jsfiddle.net/jngvsh4y/